# Durandal js cache view need a hook when transition is completed

Tags: durandal

All my durandal view is cache so the attach event only fires one. I need a hook into when the transition is completed. I review the doc and I can't find hook for it. I heard of view attach or document attached but can't find any documentation on the website. I am using durandal js 2.0. I rather not hack the transition module. I can add some code into end transition but prefer not to mess with out of the box code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The viewAttached event has been replaced by the attached event, which fires every time you goto the page.

```
var attached = function() {
    alert('Attached');
};
```

Set alwaysTriggerAttach: true in your main.js or other entry point to fire the attached each time.

Or you could hook into compositionComplete

```
var compositionComplete = function() {
    alert('Attached');
};
```

Comment: Attach event is only firing once when you have a cache view. That in the documentation. Someone please confirm.

Comment: That's not correct, re-read the doc - Remember: Rows highlighted green will always execute when composing.

Comment: If you read the document it for composing. A cache view is only compose once.

Comment: Note: If you have set cacheViews:true then attached will only be called the first time the view is shown, on the initial bind, since technically the view is only attached once. If you wish to override this behavior, then set alwaysTriggerAttach:true on your composition binding. This is in the documentation.

Comment: Touche - then why not set alwaysTriggerAttach:true?  Updated answer with that and another alternative.

Comment: I want the cache views. That's the reason for this posted.

Comment: alwaysTriggerAttach just overrides the fact that when you are caching the views, it will fire the attach event again anyways.  You will still have cached views, it will just fire attach.  you could also use the compositionComplete event like I mentioned above

Comment: This doesn't help me when I use plugin that require screen to visible for it to calculate the width like fullcalendar js. The compositecomplete works but will only fire once with cache views. Is it possible to get callback when transition is complete or have the composite complete triggered on cache views.

Answer (score 0):

```
define(function(require) {

    var viewModel = function() {

        var self = this;

        self.attached = function(view, parent) {
            console.log('view attached');
        };
    };

    return viewModel;

});
```

This way you will be returning a constructor function, and each time you call the module will return a new instance.

Comment: Please expand your answer to include an explanation.